# How to reduce Ionic2 app load time

Tags: ionic2

I am currently developing an Ionic2 app.
My app has
- Total 29 Pages
My plugins are

```
cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.2 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-zip 3.1.0 "cordova-plugin-zip"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.2 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

config.xml is almost default set.

I do `npm run ionic:build --aot + ionic prepare android --prod --release`, after that I create signed apk from android studio.

My app start time is 9-10 seconds.

How can I reduce it.

Please advice.

Comment: could you please add the code of your `app.component.ts` file? If the app takes almost 10 seconds to hide the splash screen, is because there must be a lot of things going on there...

Comment: I stripped all codes from app.component.ts, and keep it to bare minimum, till 8 sec. Cordova device ready not fired in 5 second, may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [ongoing discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/app-boot-time-current-state-and-best-practices/80690/3) on the forums about this painfull issue
For now, the possible steps may help:

- Hiding the splashscreen manually and disable autohide
- Shrink the code with rollup, make sure to build for production
- Adding lazy loading of some elements
- Upgrading to newer ionic version 3+ which brings angular4

Comment: Adding to above points, one important point is mobile processor architecture. It sets a major difference in load time.

Comment: @raju can you tell us more about that?

Comment: I have different android having 1gb ram / 2 gb ram, they have mediatek / snapdragon processor. Same Ionic2 app having many cordova plugin, loads in ~3s on one phone (1gb ram, armeabi), & same app took ~9-10s on another phone (2gb ram, arm64). On iphone 6 it is constantly 3s for same app.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue? ?